# How to Replace The Image in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I put this URL: "https://picsum.photos/200 in my js file
The goal is that in every running the image will change for every object in the array.

now it gives the same picture for all the objects. I want to change this.
what do I need to change in my code to let that happen?

How can I get another picture for every object in the array?

thx for your help!

```js
var messages = [
  {
    name: "magna aliqua",
    text:
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "asi.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "iusto odio",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "et accusamus",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "et accusamus",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "et accusamus",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "praesentium voluptatum",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "vero eos",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "iusto odio",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "quos dolores",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "ducimus qui",
    text:
      "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et",
    time: "5 hours ago",
    picture: "lior.jpg",
  },
];

function showMessages() {
  let messageBox = document.getElementById("messagesBox");
  const allTheMessage = messages.map(
    (m) =>
      `<div>    

      <hr></hr>
    <a class="avatar">
    <img class="imgOfUser" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
    </a>

    <div class="allContent">
    <span class="content">
    <a class="author">${m.name}</a>
    <span class="metadata">

    <div class="text">
    ${m.text}
    </div>
    <span class="date">${m.time}</span>
    </div>
    </div>
      
    

  
</div>     
         </div>`
  );
  messageBox.innerHTML = allTheMessage.join("");
}

showMessages();
```

```css
.author {
  color: #b62626    ;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 22PX;
}

.imgOfUser {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 131px;
}

.date {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: silver;
}


.text{
    width: 700px;
    font-size: 18PX;
    display: block;
}


.allContent{
    display: inline-block;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ticker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Ticker Demo</h1>  


  <marquee scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" direction="down">


    <h1 id="messagesBox"></h1>


    
  </marquee>


  <script src="/messages.js"></script>




  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `${m.picture}` in the url, what part do you not get?

Comment: I need that the picture will replace for every object in the array now it gives the same picture for all the objects ...

Comment: `<img class="imgOfUser" src="https://picsum.photos/200">` where did u modify this line... how are you expecting it to change? hense my question do you not want something like `<img class="imgOfUser" src="https://picsum.photos/"+${m.picture}>`